# Can't access custom pivot element (Laravel framework)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I created a relation between User and Event. I added a pivot element 'part_sure' to the pivot table and updated the models appropriately:
[image: Updated models]

Now I have a problem with accessing this pivot element. If I try to do this...
[image: display custom pivot element]
... it doesn't display anything! No error but also no value.

Looking with this command...
[image: display all pivot data]

... what is accessable in the pivot element:

[image]

As you can see, the part_sure element is not there.

My user model:
[image]

My event model:

[image]

I really don't know why this isn't working. Tried to google it for almost an hour. I would be really happy if somebody could give me a hint!

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the events method from the User model, but you aren't showing us the User model.

What does your User model look like? Just like you did with the Event model, you need to specify the extra pivot column in the User model.

User model

```
public function events() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('radclub\Event')->withPivot('part_sure');
}
```

You may need to edit `radclub\Event` with the proper namespace.

Comment: I did the same in the Event model. Still doesn't work. Do I have to refresh anything after changing the models?

Comment: Your Event model was fine, but you need to setup the relationship properly in the User model.

Comment: A many-to-many relationship should be `belongsToMany` both ways. :) In your User model, you said that a user `hasMany` events when it should be `belongsToMany`.

Comment: I'm really appreciating your help! I've changed this now (see updated User model in the question) but I still doesn't get the part_sure pivot element. Same since the beginning... Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Hm...just tried it out on my end, and it's working. Is your pivot table named "event_user" or something else?